# Browser compatibility testing in automated unit tests for new angular framework codes

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-runner, chutzpah

Is it possible to test the browser compatibility using automated JavaScript unit tests?

I have to test my angular 6 code for some dom test cases in different browser scenarios. This unit tests should run in CI build.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure karma to run multiple browsers using launchers. For example you can add the [firefox launcher](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-firefox-launcher/blob/master/README.md) or [edge launcher](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-edge-launcher/blob/master/README.md) to your `karma.config.js` file depending on what browsers you need and/or have on the CI agents.